# Does async block when using await

Tags: kotlin

In the following code two asyncs are run:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlin.system.*

fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {
    val time = measureTimeMillis {
        val one = async { doSomethingUsefulOne() }
        val two = async { doSomethingUsefulTwo() }
        two.await()
        one.await()
        println("Finished")
    }   
}

suspend fun doSomethingUsefulOne(): Int {
    delay(3000L)
    println("first")
    return 13
}

suspend fun doSomethingUsefulTwo(): Int {
    delay(1000L)
    println("second")
    return 29
}
```

Why is "Finished" not printed first? The docs says this about `await`:

> Awaits for completion of this value without blocking a thread

Comment: because `await` is a `suspend` function.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. So why do the docs say it "Awaits for completion of this value WITHOUT blocking a thread"? It is clearly blocking the thread. If it wasn't blocking, then "Finished" would print first.

Comment: NO. if it blocking the thread, other coroutines using same thread can't be executed. But if you executed other coroutines using same thread, it would be executed while `await` suspended.
Unfortunately, in this case, it doesn't work because `runBlocking` is blocking thread.

Comment: Sorry but I don't agree with that. await absolutely blocks the current thread. If it wasn't blocking, "Finished" would be printed first. If you remove the await (both of them) and run the code, "Finished" will in fact print first.

Comment: without blocking doesn't mean that it will execute next code line. it just release current thread for other jobs.

Comment: @Choim is right.

Answer (score 1):

The complete quote is:

> Awaits for completion of this value without blocking a thread and
>   resumes when deferred computation is complete, returning the resulting
>   value or throwing the corresponding exception if the deferred was
>   cancelled.

[Source](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-deferred/await.html)

**without blocking a thread**:
The execution inside other async coroutine is not blocked. Track the time and you'll see that there was no 'pause' in time execution.

**resumes when deferred computation is complete**: the main thread will wait to continue on following code (`println("Finished")`), since you force it by calling `await()` to wait for the returned value. But the executions inside coroutines are not blocked.

### EDIT

Considering the comments, I agree with [AndroidDev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/753632/androiddev) on misleading documentation. It should be changed to:

> Awaits for completion of this value without blocking **other coroutines or
>   threads**...

or

> Awaits for completion of this value **blocking only the current thread** ...

Comment: So if an await "resumes when deferred computation is complete", then that implies that it is blocking the current thread, which is what I am observing. This is why I consider the documentation either not clear or incorrect. I think what is meant is that it is not blocking the code that is running inside of the async. But it is clearly blocking the thread that is used to call the async function.

Comment: you block your current execution by calling `await`, but the execution of blocks in async started at the point where you defined them, this works exactly as intended since this way you don't have to deal with any concurrency problems at the cost of explicitly awaiting for result when you require it.

Comment: "you block your current execution by calling await" which is what I said. It blocks. It is clear that the docs are kind of wrong. When it says "without blocking a thread", the word "a" should really be replaced with "the async". It was clear to me that the code inside the async is never going to get blocked. But the thread that calls await IS blocked.

Comment: Your proposition won't get right only by repeating it again and again. While it's true that the block of execution is blocked, it remains false, that the thread is blocked.The thread could do other work, if there were any. It's common sense that println("Finished") won''t get executed before await() has returned successfully. 
BTW If an exception were thrown within async, that exception would be propagated to await and println("Finished") wouldn't be executed at all.

Answer (score 0):

By slightly modifying the code, one will gain some insights. Let's add the elapsed time and the current thread to the print statements to see, what's going on:

[Execute on kotlin playground](https://pl.kotl.in/6xCSpBf04)

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlin.system.*

private val started = System.currentTimeMillis()

private fun debug(s: String) {
    val elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - started
    println("[$elapsed] $s  --  ${Thread.currentThread()}")
}

fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {
    val time = measureTimeMillis {
        val one = async { doSomethingUsefulOne() }
        val two = async { doSomethingUsefulTwo() }
        debug("awaiting")
        two.await()
        one.await()
        debug("Finished")
    }
    debug("time = $time")
}

suspend fun doSomethingUsefulOne(): Int {
    delay(3000L)
    debug("first")
    return 13
}

suspend fun doSomethingUsefulTwo(): Int {
    delay(1000L)
    debug("second")
    return 29
}
```

When run with `-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug` one should see something similar to

```
[46] awaiting  --  Thread[main @coroutine#1,5,main]
[1056] second  --  Thread[main @coroutine#3,5,main]
[3054] first  --  Thread[main @coroutine#2,5,main]
[3054] Finished  --  Thread[main @coroutine#1,5,main]
[3054] time = 3013  --  Thread[main @coroutine#1,5,main]
```

**There is only one single thread.**

If `await` had  blocked the thread, the program could not have terminated.