# Why the 'await' blocks the thread in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, async-await

The api description of 'await':

> Awaits for completion of this value without blocking a thread and resumes when deferred computation is complete, returning the resulting value or throwing the corresponding exception if the deferred was cancelled.

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
    val one = async { doSomethingUsefulOne() }
    println("start->" + System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000)
    one.await()
    println("end->" + System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000)
}

suspend fun doSomethingUsefulOne(): Int {
    delay(3000L)
    return 13
}
```

Result:

start->1575977567

end->1575977570

There are three seconds gap between 'start' and 'end'.So this line 'one.await()' blocks the thread. Why it is different from what the api says.

Comment: The Thread is *NOT* blocked. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59204919/4774054

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It *doesn't necessarily* block the thread. The execution of the coroutine built from the lambda you passed to `runBlocking { ... }` *suspends* at `one.await()` and then resumes once the `one` result is ready. During that time, the thread that executed the coroutine could switch to executing another coroutine, if it had any. But it doesn't because, by calling `runBlocking { ... }`, you explicitly specified that you want to run the coroutine in the current single thread, using the thread exclusively until the coroutine finishes and thus just blocking the thread when the coroutine suspends and there's no other coroutine to run.

For instance, if you add a second pair of `async { ... }` + `await` in the `testAsyncAwait` function, the `await` calls will actually execute concurrently.

You could also run this coroutine using a different dispatcher that explicitly supports running multiple coroutines, and you would see that the `one.await()` call doesn't block the thread in that case.

For instance, you can run this as follows:

```
suspend fun doSomethingUsefulOne(): Int {
    delay(3000L)
    return 13
}

suspend fun testAsyncAwait(n: Int) = coroutineScope {
    val one = async { doSomethingUsefulOne() }
    println("start $n ->" + System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000)
    one.await()
    println("end $n ->" + System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000)
}

suspend fun main() = coroutineScope {
    val context = newSingleThreadContext("MyOwnThread")
    repeat(2) {
        launch(context) { testAsyncAwait(it) }
    }
}
```

The two coroutines will run concurrently, and `one.await()` should not block the single thread:

```
start 0 -> 1575982105
start 1 -> 1575982106
end 0 -> 1575982109
end 1 -> 1575982109
```

See these sections in the language reference:

- [Coroutine Context and Dispatchers. Dispatchers and threads](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html#dispatchers-and-threads)
- [Coroutine Basics. Bridging blocking and non-blocking worlds](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html#bridging-blocking-and-non-blocking-worlds)

Answer (score 2):

`delay(3000)` delays for 3 seconds -- that has to work, so you *want* to see 3 seconds between your outputs.

During those 3 seconds, the thread is not blocked by `await`, however.  It's blocked by `runBlocking`, because it is waiting for your coroutine to complete.  If you had launched other asychronous coroutines inside `runBlocking`, then they could execute during this time.